# Show that $S(x) = \int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}f(t)dt \implies S'(x) = f(g(x))g'(x)-f(h(x))h'(x)$

Tags: integration, derivatives

let $g(x), h(x)$ be derivatible functions in $R$ and let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in $R$.

$S(x) = \int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}f(t)dt$.

How can I prove:

$S'(x) = f(g(x))g'(x)-f(h(x))h'(x)$.

Comment: You might try looking up the Fundamental Theorems of Calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(x)=\int{f(x)}dx$, then $S(x)=F(g(x))-F(h(x))$ and so $S'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F(g(x))-\frac{d}{dx}F(h(x))$.

By the chain rule $\frac{d}{dx}F(h(x))=h'(x)F'(h(x))$ and $\frac{d}{dx}F(g(x))=g'(x)F'(g(x))$, but $F'(x)=f(x)$, so we have $S'(x)=g'(x)f(g(x))-h'(x)f(h(x)) $ as required.

Answer (score 0):

Not very rigorous, but useful to help to remember the rule:

Let $F(x)=\int f(t)\mathrm dt$, so is, a primitive of $f$, then $F'(x)=f(x)$

$S(x)=\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}f(t)dt=[F(t)]_{h(x)}^{g(x)}=F(g(x))-F(h(x))$

$S'(x)=F'(g(x))g'(x)-F'(h(x))h('(x)=f((g(x))g'(x)-f(h(x))h'(x)$